# Mysql update not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues updating a row in my mysql database.
I created a textarea which contains data from a news article. If i edit the data and try to update it, nothing happens.
I'm aware that the mysql extension is depreciated so please dont comment on that.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$data = mysql_query("SELECT news_content FROM news WHERE id= 1") ;
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
$news= $info['news_content']; 
?>
<h3>EDIT NEWS ARTICLE</h3>

<form id="EditNews" name="EditNews" method="POST"action="edit.php">            
<textarea rows="40" cols="90" name="editnewstext"><?php echo $news?></textarea> 
<input type="submit" name="Edit_News" id="Edit_News">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Edit_news'])) {
    $contents= $_POST['editnewstext'];
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE news SET news_content ='$contents' WHERE id=1";
    mysql_query($sqlupdate) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I'm commenting on it anyway because you ***should*** stop using it.

Comment: PLEASE look into mysqli or PDO for your sql queries, the current query is completely open to sql injection, as the text from the textbox is directly used within your query.

Comment: `<?php Print $daisy?>` is a typo?

Comment: @JonTaylor: I have to add that I recommend using prepared statements; it's very easy to write code using MySQLi and PDO that's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` `echo $sqlupdate;` should point you in the right direction. p.s. i'd `<?php echo $daisy; ?>`

Comment: input is called "Edit_News" and your code expects to see "Edit_news"

Comment: @MarcelKorpel yes very true, I tend to put the two hand in hand really, I hardly ever write a non prepared statement in mysqli, even with no external parameters I still write them out of habbit now.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="submit" name="Edit_News" id="Edit_News">
                           ^^^^^^^^^^

if(isset($_POST['Edit_news'])) {
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Case mis-match. PHP array keys are CASE-SENSITIVE.

That being said, your code is wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy getting your server pwn3d.

Comment: Doesn't the `<input>` also need a `value` attribute?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Dont know how i missed that

Comment: @rocket: no. just the name parameter is necessary. e.g. FF will fill in a submit value of "Submit Query" automatically if nothing else is provided.

Comment: No, even not the name parameter is necessary, [only the `type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html#input.submit).

Comment: @marcel: yeah, but the OP's form is explicitly checking for the presence of the submit button's name, so it is necessary in this case.